# I'm getting the wrong Hamiltonian of the quantum oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

First, I generalised the oscillator's Hamilton's equations to complex variables:

$$\frac{dz_1}{dt}=\frac{\partial (z_1^2+z_2^2)}{\partial z_1}=2z_1$$

$$\frac{dz_2}{dt}=2z_2$$

So the real world oscillator will correspond to a subset of this theory in which $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both real.

Then I changed the variables:

$$z'_1=z_1+iz_2$$

$$z'_2=z_1-iz_2$$

In terms of these variables, the oscillator becomes $$H=z'_1z'_2$$

The real world oscillator corresponds to the subset in which $z'_1=(z'_2)^{*}$

Then I promoted $z'_1$ and $z'_2$ to operators satisfying $$[Z'_1, Z'_2]=i\frac{h}{2\pi}$$

So the quantum Hamiltonian I ended up with is:

$$H=Z'_1Z'_2$$
This is identical to $H=\frac{h}{2\pi}\omega (a^{\dagger} a+1)$, EXCEPT the ground state energy is missing. Futhermore $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ satisfy $[a,a^{\dagger}=1]$ instead of $[a, a^{\dagger}]=i\frac{h}{2\pi}$.

So what did I do wrong? I really want to get the quantum theory by promoting $z'_1$ and $z_2'$ instead of by promoting $p$ and $q$

Comment: Classically, the same hamiltonian is $H = z'_2 z'_1$. So why not take your quantum hamiltonian to be $H = Z'_2 Z'_1$? Maybe you can see that there are many other choices for $H$ that also work, including one that gets you back the constant term. You didn't do anything wrong, it's just that there's more than one right answer.

Comment: @d_b Shit, that makes sense. I remember reading something about doing $\frac{1}{2}(AB+BA)$ in such situations

Comment: If you're missing the ground state, it's *possible* that you've actually derived the [supersymmetric partner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetric_quantum_mechanics) to the SHO Hamiltonian, instead of the SHO Hamiltonian itself.